# oracle stored procedure generates an compliation error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

This is a simple procedure and it generated a ORA -24344 compilation error and PLS - 00103. Please help in clearing them

```
create or replace PROCEDURE test (v_price in number)
IS
BEGIN 
    if ROWNUM = 0
        insert into admin (price) values (v_price);
    else 
        update admin set price = v_price; 
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: Please format your code.  You are missing THEN keyword.  Go read the PL/SQL docs.

Comment: `if rownum = 0` isn't going to work. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: My functionality is to insert a new price into the price column if there are zero rowns in it. If there are one or more rows then it should perform the update operation. am i clear on this ?

Comment: @Krish - So your `admin` table can only ever have 0 or 1 rows?  That seems like an unlikely data model.

Comment: @JustinCave..yes thats what i need. Why is it unlikely, could you please elobrate?

Comment: Do a `select count(*) into <my_variable> from admin`, then check `my_variable = 0` instead of `rownum  = 0`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog...thanks a lot. I guess thats working just perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `then` after the condition :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE test (v_price in number) IS
rn number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into rn from admin;
  if rn = 0 THEN
    insert into admin (price) values (v_price);
  else
    update admin set price = v_price;
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It still shows ORA 24344 error success with compilation error and PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'ROWNUM' may be used inside a SQL statement only. Please help me in correcting this as well.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. That's fixed.